# rsync over NFS - inconsistent speed

Tags: rsync, nfs

I'm transferring about 9TB across my gigabit LAN.  To do so as quickly as possible (i hope) I mounted the destination via NFS on the source and ran rsync across it.

Here is my mount options: 
`x.x.x.x:/mnt on /mnt type nfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=x.x.x.x,mountvers=3,mountport=56548,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=x.x.x.x)`

Here is my rsync command: `rsync -avWH --progress ./ /mnt/`

looking at nload, what i see, for a single file is speed that spikes up to 900MBps then down to numbers in the KBps range, then back up.  Here is a graphic from nload where you can see that the transfer seems to stop, midfile. The files are all typically 5-6GB in size. MTU is 9000; switch is a cisco 3750x with plenty of backplane speed. These are esxi 6.7 guests on 2 different hosts. There are no other guests that contend for network resources.

[image: Nload]

This image is ONE file being sent

Basically, I'm hoping there is a setting I have wrong or something I can change to keep the transfer speed somewhat consistent.

CPU utilization on the source is approximately 10%, on the dest is approximately 10%. The strange thing is that on the destination, iotop shows 99% i/o (sometimes) from nfsd, the source shows 60-80% IO from rsync. These are 7200RPM WD red drives. w

Comment: Are source and destination systems Unix/Linux, and if so do you have a login on them both?

Comment: If this is a Linux system, it could be a problem from the filesystem cache implementation that is known to have idle times.

Comment: @roaima yes, they're both linux and I have root on both.

Comment: @schily the strange thing is, interesting, I hadn't noticed with wget but I will test again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately just about the worst thing you can do is to use `rsync` across NFS. (Or to any remote filesystem that's mounted into the local system.) This switches off almost all of the efficiency enhancements for which `rsync` is known.

For this much data one of the fastest ways to transfer it between systems may be to dump it across an *unencrypted* connection without any consideration for what was already on the target system.

Once you have at least a partial copy the best option is to use `rsync` between the two hosts. This allows `rsync` to run one process on each host to consider and compare differences. (The `rsync` will completely skip files that have the same size and modification date. For other files the client and server components will perform a rolling checksum to determine which block(s) need still to be transferred.)

1. Fast dump. This example uses no authentication or encryption at all. It does apply compression, though, which you can remove by omitting both `-z` flags:

   Run this on the destination machine to start a listening server:

   ```
   cd /path/to/destination && nc -l 50505 | pax -zrv -pe
   ```

   Run this on the source machine to start the sending client:

   ```
   cd /path/to/source && pax -wz . | nc destination_server 50505
   ```

   Some versions of `nc -l` may require the port to be specified with a flag, i.e. `nc -l -p 50505`. The OpenBSD version on Debian (`nc.openbsd`, linked via `/etc/alternatives` to `/bin/nc`) does not.
2. Slower transfer. This example uses `rsync` over `ssh`, which provides authentication and encryption. Don't miss off the trailing slash (`/`) on the source path. Omit the `-z` flag if you don't want compression:

   ```
   rsync -avzP /path/to/source/ destination_server:/path/to/destination
   ```

You may need to set up SSH certificates to allow login to destination_server as root. Add the `-H` flag if you need to handle hard links.

Comment: I attempted your commands, with Z i'm throttled, so once this test transfer completed, i'll remove compression to fully utilize my link (GREAT Tool, how did i not know of it!) Anyway, the destination side needed to be nc -l -p 50505, but this appears to be working. it definitely doesn't seem any faster than my rsync over nfs, but the transfer is MUCH more stable. -- Removing the z options gave me a stable 800-900Mbps with no more transfer gaps!!

Comment: One thing I noticed is that I love my permissions and ownership settings and presumably this won't follow hard-links. luckily, a post pax rsync should resolve the hard links but i think im on my own for permissions. ustar apparently also has a limit "pax: File is too long for ustar " it looks like pax -pe might take care of the ownership/mode issue

Comment: @driz apologies, you're right about `-pe`. I'll amend the answer. Re `nc -l -p` I think there are a number of different (and slightly incompatible) versions of `nc` floating around. I'll flag it up in my answer but my version definitely works here.

Comment: no apologies necessary, this is so much faster than what I was doing. I'll have to go back to transfer the files that were too long/large for pax, but this nc blackmagic will likely help me out there too.

Comment: @driz remember that `rsync` will "fill in the gaps", so if you've 9TB to copy but you've done, say, 8TB of it, the `rsync` command in my answer will just transfer the missing 1TB. It's inherently restartable and will only copy data that's missing from the destination. It will also fix up permissions, ownerships, etc., and even make the evening meal. (Well, maybe not the meal.)

Comment: yep, it's just that it's 3TB of data ;) im impatient, but yah, all good man. thanks again!

Comment: This is an interesting comment. RedHat 8 has removed pax from it's repositories. So I presume it's easy enough to replace with tar? Further - what if both servers are on separate networks for security reasons? Is it possible to chain nc servers together with a middle machine? And would that impact on transfer speed?

Answer (score 10):

It is far better to use rsync directly between two hosts if possible. Remember, rsync is built to optimise network IO at the cost of increased disk IO; when using rsync on an NFS filesystem, disk IO translates to network IO, so that is a very suboptimal solution. Also if rsync thinks that both source and destination is local, it will switch off the optimizations and transfer complete files every time, instead of using the differential algorithm that only sends the differences.

Say you have a 5GB file that only differs in 1% of the data between source and destination.

- When transferring between hosts, rsync will checksum the source and destination files, and only transfer the difference; on the destination the file is recreated using the old file and the new data from the source, and then the old file is replaced.
- When transferring locally, it makes no sense to checksum each file, meaning you'd have to read 2 x 5GB and write 1 x 5GB for the example file. By switching to whole file mode, rsync only needs to read 1 x 5GB and write 1 x 5GB. On local disks this makes complete sense, when one is NFS the network bandwidth shoots through the roof.

If you can use rsync directly to the host serving the NFS filesystem, then do that, you will see a big improvement in the performance.