# Rsync remove-source-files , is taking too much time to delete source?

Tags: linux, rsync

Im using NFS server to store some big datas.

There are 10k+ of files ( 1 file is around 10MiB+ ) there in the location.

In my host system i mounted nfs share , and tried to rsync from mount point to host directory called /demo with `--remove-source-files` option.

Command works fine and files are being copied.

My network is 10G and im getting full throughput during this process.

But i noticed that, after copying one file from source nfs directory to /demo , rsync is taking time (5+ mins) to delete that source file.

Is this normal behavior of rsync?

/demo is empty directory as well, so no quick-scan required

How exactly `--remove-source-files` works?

Any rsync expert, please.

Comment: For that amount of files, I would say that this would probably be normal behaviour for _NFS_, not `rsync`.  For performance, you rarely want to do bulk delete/create operations over NFS if you can avoid it. Not turning this into an answer because I don't feel I have quite enough experience working with NFS to say that this is true.

Comment: May be you are right, 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450537/rsync-over-nfs-inconsistent-speed

Comment: Note that that question is mainly regarding the speed of data transfer, not about the speed of file deletion, but it's related, yes.

Comment: The question is valid for few (say heavy files) too, resync seems to remove files in batches. Which sometimes is not desired at all.