# NFS4 performance tuning for use with rsync

Tags: rsync, nfs

[To open, I know that this is a bad idea, and should be avoided.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450537/rsync-over-nfs-inconsistent-speed) However, we currently have no choice as our NFS server is a Netapp SAN, which means we can't just run rsync to the file server.

What I am currently experiencing is when the volume is mounted using NFS4 (4.2 specifically), the majority of the time the transfer is inactive when using rsync between the mount point and an internal hard drive:

[image: Screen capture from Ontap showing volume only periodically in use]

This was mounted with the following line from `/etc/fstab`:

```
netapp:/repository  /netapp/repository                  nfs     rw,nfsvers=4.2,async,_netdev  0 0
```

When the volume was remounted as NFS3, the performance became consistent and matched the I/O speed of the hard drive:

[image: Screen capture from Ontap showing volume in steady use]

This was mounted with the command:

```
mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3,proto=tcp,async,_netdev netapp:/repository /netapp/repository
```

So it seems obvious to me that the issue is `rsync` and NFS4 not playing nice with each other, as is to be expected, but I did not expect it would be to the point of NFS4 not doing anything 80% of the time. Since `krb5p` security is preferred I would prefer to be able to begin using NFS4 on this service, however I am stumped as to what could be causing this. Are there any performance tweaks I could make on the host that might alleviate this strange starting and stopping of transfers?

Comment: hm! Why do you use `rsync` then, instead of just `cp` to copy over things? Maybe the answer lies in optimizing NFS for that use case, rather than for rsync.

Comment: You explicitly specified `proto=tcp` for NFSv3. I don't know whether TCP is the default method for NFSv4 on netapp appliances, as well (I don't know whether UDP or TCP is more useful in your scenario – packet loss is rather rare these days in uncongested local area networks, so the `man nfs` advice might be a bit dated.) If you use `proto=tcp` (or implicitly use TCP), then specifying `nconnect` might help the "the client is waiting for a reply and can't ask the next thing" issue – though rsync is pretty sequential in nature. Maybe you could then rsync sub-directories in parallel faster?

Comment: @MarcusMüller We use `rsync` primarily to take advantage of the `--compare-dest` flag; there is a second volume mounted that contains a copy of the repository in it's per-synchronization state. By only transferring the differential between the current and the last transfer, it saves us hours on both ends.

Comment: Ah, also it defaults to `proto=tcp`, I don't know why I specified it with NFS3. But you can see it in the mount line for the other volume I just mentioned: `netapp:/repository_everything_rsync on /netapp/repo_everything type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=krb5p,clientaddr=[snipped],local_lock=none,addr=[snipped],_netdev)` This is the one used for comparing. I've tried mounting it with `nconnect`, which should be supported in out client's kernel, but it never showed up in the displayed mount options after mounting

Comment: To what value did you set nconnect?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I tried both 2 and 8, the NFS client has only 12 cores, so both should be safely under that and the nconnect limit. (It is also Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.4.0-147-generic which I believe should come with support for nconnect based upon my reading)